# SPSS: How to get the range of b standard erorr ± of coefficient in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic-regression, spss, standard-error

I did a binary logistic regression and in the output (in the saction "Variables in the equation") I find the B coefficient and its standard error (ex S.E. = .859). However, I need the **range** of the beta standard erorr, somthing like: beta ± SE 0.05 ± 0.09.

How can I get Spss to show this value in the output or compute this value on my own?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the output table into a new dataset - using `OMS` command, then you can use it to make calculations:

```
DATASET DECLARE  mydata.
OMS /SELECT TABLES
    /IF COMMANDS=['Logistic Regression'] SUBTYPES=['Variables in the Equation']
    /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV OUTFILE='mydata' .
*run your analysis here.
omsend.
dataset activate mydata.
```

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answer.
I think I shoud have mentioned, that I am new to statistics and spss and have not worked with code directly yet. So I cannot readily apply your solution.
I don't know how to use OMS command. I could of corse find out. But it would take time..

Is there another way, like using the spss menu bar?

Comment: Actually I rarely work with the menus - you should learn to use SPSS syntax - that's an investment with quick and huge returns... but in the meantime go to the menu for UTILITIES -> OMS control panel and try from there.